# Magento: virtual products not showing

Tags: magento, virtual, product

I'm building a magento website. now I've one main category "services" and a child category temporarily named "subcat", this category contains 2 products, one "real" and one virtual, but only the real one is showed up on the front end. I checked all the field in the product configuration but alll seems to be ok.

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure if all products are active and there is no condition which cause hiding them.
(especially EAV attributes Visibility in Catalog and Search, Status is set to Active, Have items or store, or have disabled selling only store items), reindex, clean cashes!

Comment: the product is visible in both catalog and search and is active index and chache hes been refreshed and cleaned. but i don't understand what do you mean with "Have items or store, or have disabled selling only store items".

Comment: Default magento config did not shows items which is not on store, that means in Magento admin / catalog / manage products / your_product / stock inventory on left side, there are numeric field qty, need to be positive value, (not zero) and must be selected "On Store" in select field.

Comment: ok, that solved the problem. i wonder what's the point of needing a quantity on virtual items...

Comment: virtual items can be limited for selling too, you can, for example buy limited number of SW licences to resell them as virtual product.